# XCODE can't find compiler button

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode7

Whenever I open my project I only see what is shown in this picture:
[image: How it looks for me]

I can neither see the toolbar nor the compile button (play). The following picture is how it suppose to look like.

[image: This is how it is suppose to look like]

I have just started programming so I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: I think you're opening your `main.c` file, instead of your `safafasf.xcodeproj` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing in the first picture is Xcode opening a *file*. In the second picture, you have a *project*.

Open the `.xcodeproj` file to get the second view. If you just open a file you won't get any compile buttons or anything because there are no project settings to tell Xcode how to compile.

Answer (score -2):

On the top bar, Go to View->Show Toolbar